# Is there an equation for a solution's electrical conduction as temperature varies?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, electrochemistry

I'm looking for an equation that determines a solution's ability to conduct electricity as temperature varies, that hopefully could offer insight to a salt water experiment.

I did an experiment recently where I measured a salt water solution's ability to conduct electricity as temperature varied. I got an inversely proportional relationship to the one all textbooks and other sources gave me (where instead, as temperature increased, conductivity *decreased*).

Is there an explanation for this, or something I should consider looking into for one? I'm sure about the relationship I observed but can't find enough on this topic to investigate further.

[image]
[image]

I used 1g salt in 200 ml of water and my temperature variations ranged from roughly 2-76 degrees Celsius (as seen above in a simple data representation).

Comment: Can you give more detail? Did the conductivity increase or decrease with temperature? What was the salt concentration? What was the temperature range? Please include a graph if possible.

Comment: Please see edits. Would you like more info? I apologize if its unhelpful as my data set is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like conductivity of liquid solutions increases with temperature (https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/temperature-effects-on-conductivity-of-seawater-and-physiologic-salinemechanism-and-significance-2150-3494-1000109.pdf , Sauerheber and Heinz, Chem Sci J 2015, 6:4). so I am not sure your results contradict existing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

According to Arps formula:

$$R_{2} =R_{1} \frac{T_{1} + 21.5}{T2+21.5}$$

Since $122.962 \mu S/cm = 0.0123 \Omega$. m your conductivity at $21.77 ~ ^{o}C$ is about $270 \mu S/cm$.
In other words your result is ok.
Rick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).